# How to subtract value in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Could you please tell me how to subtract value in xslt using a variable?

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentCurpg" select="1"/>
<xsl:variable name="tCurpg" select="($currentCurpg-1)"/>
```

The variable `tCurpg` should be `zero` or `0`.

Why I am getting error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
         <xsl:variable name="currentCurpg" select="1"/>
          <xsl:variable name="tCurpg" select="($currentCurpg-1)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$tCurpg"/>

      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

I am expecting output `zero`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that hyphens are valid in variable names, so when you do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="tCurpg" select="($currentCurpg-1)"/>
```

It is literally looking for a variable named `currentCurpg-1`.

Instead change it to this...

```
<xsl:variable name="tCurpg" select="$currentCurpg - 1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the curly {} braces around your variable are not need in an xslt statement only in html

```
eg div title="{$currentCurpg}">
```

so in your code you need

```
<xsl:for-each select="ul/li[position() &gt;= (last()-$currentCurpg) and position() &lt;= last()-1]">
```

**Updated**
Based on your updated code you need to drop the () and put spaces between the variable  and the - 1 like this

```
 <xsl:variable name="tCurpg" select="$currentCurpg - 1"/>
```

Comment: You need to drop the () and put spaces between variable name and -1   per my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` attribute value `ul/li[position() &gt;= last()-{$currentCurpg} and position() &lt;= last()-1]` is invalid. In XSLT attributes, you use XSLT variables directly, so the curly brackets shouldn't be present. In other words, use `ul/li[position() &gt;= last()-$currentCurpg and position() &lt;= last()-1]`.

Also, in `<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />`, the correct value for `doctype-public` is `about:legacy-compat`; see [HTML §12.1.1: The DOCTYPE](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype).

And declaring `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` is pointless for HTML since HTML generated with `method="html"` isn't XML and will therefore never have an XML declaration.

Edit: The OP apparently initially linked to the wrong code which also had errors.

Comment: @user944513 It's not working because you didn't put a space character between the variable and the minus sign, so the minus sign is being interpreted as a hyphen. Your variable is therefore named `$currentCurpg-1` (which doesn't exist) instead of `$currentCurpg`.

Comment: @user944513 Also, `hmtl` should be `html`.